# Дерево для элементов - Angular 6 + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, дерево, angular

В общем нужно написать дерево в связке TS + Angular 6. Дерево выводится как надо, оно изначально скрытое и при нажатии на выбранный элемент открываются дочерние. Только вот если у дочерних есть свои дети, то при открытии дочернего элемента закрывается вся ветка. Потом при повторном открытии первого (родительского) элемента, уже будет открыт дочерний элемент и его дети.
Как исправить что бы при открытии дочерних элементов ветка не скрывалась?

На вход дерева поступают данные вида:

**tree-data.ts:**

```
import {ITreeComponent} from './tree.component';

export const treesConst:ITreeComponent[] = [
    {
        "leaf":true,
        "parentCategoryId":10001,
        "categoryName":"Первый родитель",
        "categoryId":10500,
        "url":"first-parent",
        "trees":
        [{
            "leaf":false,
            "parentCategoryId":10500,
            "categoryName":"Ребенок первого родителя",
            "categoryId":10515,
            "url":"children-first-parent",
            "trees":[]
        }]
    },
    {
        "leaf":true,
        "parentCategoryId":10001,
        "categoryName":"Второй родитель",
        "categoryId":10102,
        "url":"second-parent",
        "trees":
        [{
            "leaf":true,
            "parentCategoryId":10102,
            "categoryName":"Первый ребенок второго родителя",
            "categoryId":10614,
            "url":"first-children-second-parent",
            "trees":
            [{
                "leaf":false,
                "parentCategoryId":10614,
                "categoryName":"Внук",
                "categoryId":10633,
                "url":"vanok",
                "trees":[]
            },
            {
                "leaf":false,
                "parentCategoryId":10614,
                "categoryName":"Внучара",
                "categoryId":10634,
                "url":"big-boy",
                "trees":[]
            },
            {
                "leaf":false,
                "parentCategoryId":10614,
                "categoryName":"Внучка",
                "categoryId":10867,
                "url":"top-one-princes-good-girl",
                "trees":[]
            }]
        },
        {
            "leaf":true,
            "parentCategoryId":10102,
            "categoryName":"Второй ребенок второго родителя",
            "categoryId":10473,
            "url":"second-children-second-parent",
            "trees":
            [{
                "leaf":false,
                "parentCategoryId":10473,
                "categoryName":"Внук",
                "categoryId":10478,
                "url":"vano",
                "trees":[]
            },
            {
                "leaf":false,
                "parentCategoryId":10473,
                "categoryName":"Внучка",
                "categoryId":10475,
                "url":"olya",
                "trees":[]
            }]
        }]
    },
    {
        "leaf":true,
        "parentCategoryId":10001,
        "categoryName":"Соседка из квартиры 66",
        "categoryId":10105,
        "url":"sosedka-rembo",
        "trees":
        [{
            "leaf":false,
            "parentCategoryId":10105,
            "categoryName":"Сын маминой подруги",
            "categoryId":10360,
            "url":"cool-boy",
            "trees":[]
        }]
    }
];
```

**tree.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export interface ITreeComponent {
  leaf: boolean;
  parentCategoryId: number;
  categoryName: string;
  categoryId: number;
  url: string;
  trees: Array<ITreeComponent>;
  isExpanded?: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tree-view',
//  templateUrl: "./tree.component.html",
  template: `
    <ul class="treecomponents">
        <li *ngFor="let tree of SendTrees" class="treecomponent">
            <div class="nodeinfo" class="nodebutton fa fa-{{tree.isExpanded ? 'minus' : 'plus'}}-square-o" (click)="onExpand(tree)">
                <i *ngIf="tree.leaf" class="nodeicon fa fa-file-o"></i>
                <i *ngIf="!tree.leaf" class="nodeicon fa fa-tags"></i>

                <span class="nodetext {{tree == SelectedNode ? 'bg-info' : ''}} {{tree.parentCategoryId ? '' : 'text-root'}}" (click)="onSelectNode(tree)">
                (Parent: {{tree.parentCategoryId}}) {{tree.categoryName}}. Id: {{tree.categoryId}}.
                </span>

                <tree-view [SendTrees]="tree.trees" [SelectedNode]="SelectedNode" (onSelectedChanged)="onSelectNode($event)" (onRequestNodes)="onRequestLocal($event)" *ngIf="tree.isExpanded">
                </tree-view>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
  `,
//  styleUrls: ["./tree.component.css"]
  styles: [
        '.treecomponents {display:table; list-style-type: none; padding-left: 16px;}',
        '.treecomponent { display: table-row; list-style-type: none; }',
        '.nodebutton { display:table-cell; cursor: pointer; }',
        '.nodeinfo { display:table-cell; padding-left: 5px; list-style-type: none; }',
        '.nodetext { padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; cursor: pointer; }',
        '.nodetext.bg-info { font-weight: bold; }',
        '.nodetext.text-root { font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; }'
    ]
})

export class TreeComponent {
  @Input() SendTrees: Array<ITreeComponent>;    // Список узлов на данном уровне
  @Input() SelectedNode: ITreeComponent;        // Выбранный пользователем узел

  @Output() onSelectedChanged: EventEmitter<ITreeComponent> = new EventEmitter<ITreeComponent>();   // Смена выбранного пользователем узла
  @Output() onRequestNodes: EventEmitter<ITreeComponent> = new EventEmitter<ITreeComponent>();      // Запрос узлов при необходимости

  constructor(){}

  onSelectNode(node: ITreeComponent) {
    this.onSelectedChanged.emit(node);
  }

  onExpand(node: ITreeComponent) {
    if(node.leaf)
    {
        node.isExpanded = !node.isExpanded;
        if (node.isExpanded && (!node.trees || node.trees.length === 0)) {
          this.onRequestNodes.emit(node);
        }
    }
  }

  onRequestLocal(node: ITreeComponent) {
    this.onRequestNodes.emit(node);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { treesConst } from './tree/tree-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  treesData = treesConst;
}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <h1>Пробный рекурсивный вывод</h1>
    <tree-view [SendTrees]="treesData"
                    [SelectedNode]="selectedNode">
    </tree-view>
</div>
```

Вот как выводит:

[image: Вывод]

Comment: а что не так с уже существующим кодом?

Comment: @Grundy не могу никак сделать что бы ветки изначально были скрыты и была возможность их раскрывать и скрывать.

Comment: а что в данном коде за скрытость отвечает?

Comment: чем INodeComponent Отличается от ITreeComponent? Ты уверен что в INodeComponent есть поле isExpanded которое ты пытаешься использовать?

Comment: @Grundy а, там все в порядке, просто копировал из модифицированного примера сюда код. P.S. Сча обновлю весь код на актуальный (5 мин)

Comment: Так, теперь isExpand Не используется нигде. Возвращай его использование. И смотри на что конкретно и на какие строки будет ругаться компилятор

Comment: @Grundy Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79372/discussion-between-sanvirtus-and-grundy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) и все стало работать:

```
template: `
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<ul class="treecomponents">
  <li *ngFor="let tree of SendTrees" class="treecomponent">
    <i class="btn btn-light glyphicon glyphicon-{{tree.isExpanded ? 'minus' : 'plus'}}" (click)="onExpand(tree)"></i>
    <div class="nodeinfo">

      <span (click)="onSelectNode(tree)">
            {{tree.categoryName}}
            </span>

      <tree-view-mg-by [SendTrees]="tree.trees" [SelectedNode]="SelectedNode" (onSelectedChanged)="onSelectNode($event)" (onRequestNodes)="onRequestLocal($event)" *ngIf="tree.isExpanded">
      </tree-view-mg-by>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
`
```

**Вывод:**

[image: Вывод]